# im working on a discord music bot and i get this error whem im trying to run it

Tags: javascript

```
const Distube = new Distube(client, {searchSongs: false, enitNewSongsOnly: true});
      
      ^

SyntaxError: Identifier 'Distube' has already been declared
←[90m    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:16)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m
```

Comment: `Distube` has already been declared, e.g., in its `import` or `require`. Consider naming the variable differently than something that already exists, like, say, `distube`.

Comment: Change the name of the constant u are overwriting the Distube function.

Answer (score -1):

U need to name your variable rather than Distube because the class Distube is already registered.

```
const music = new Distube(client, {searchSongs: false, enitNewSongsOnly: true});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).